# What does the :ci in npm run build:ci do?

Tags: npm, build, continuous-integration, yaml

In our github workflows `yml` file, I see `run: npm run build:ci` replacing `run: npm run build`. What does the `:ci` part do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually something we defined in our package.json. Disabling linking for CI purposes.

[image]

Comment: Please don’t post code or data as an image. Instead, paste text as text, and format as code using Markdown. Can you [edit] this answer?